# Java Selenium scraping characters not displayed

Tags: java, string, selenium, encoding, utf-8

I am currently trying to scrape address data from a [website](https://www.dhs.de/service/suchthilfeverzeichnis?tx_wwdhseinrichtung2_fe1%5Baction%5D=list&tx_wwdhseinrichtung2_fe1%5Bangebot%5D=0&tx_wwdhseinrichtung2_fe1%5Bbland%5D=0&tx_wwdhseinrichtung2_fe1%5Bcontroller%5D=Entry&tx_wwdhseinrichtung2_fe1%5Bdo%5D=search&tx_wwdhseinrichtung2_fe1%5Bplzort%5D=&tx_wwdhseinrichtung2_fe1%5Bspezi%5D=0&tx_wwdhseinrichtung2_fe1%5Bsprache%5D=0&tx_wwdhseinrichtung2_fe1%5Bumkreis%5D=0&tx_wwdhseinrichtung2_fe1%5Bzielgruppe%5D=0&cHash=69c2978df7ab94262c40a535ae021a1d).

I am using Selenium and the code so far is very simple:

```
public class Scraper {
    
    public static void main(String[] args){

        String baseUrl = "https://www.dhs.de/service/suchthilfeverzeichnis?tx_wwdhseinrichtung2_fe1%5Baction%5D=list&tx_wwdhseinrichtung2_fe1%5Bangebot%5D=0&tx_wwdhseinrichtung2_fe1%5Bbland%5D=0&tx_wwdhseinrichtung2_fe1%5Bcontroller%5D=Entry&tx_wwdhseinrichtung2_fe1%5Bdo%5D=search&tx_wwdhseinrichtung2_fe1%5Bplzort%5D=&tx_wwdhseinrichtung2_fe1%5Bspezi%5D=0&tx_wwdhseinrichtung2_fe1%5Bsprache%5D=0&tx_wwdhseinrichtung2_fe1%5Bumkreis%5D=0&tx_wwdhseinrichtung2_fe1%5Bzielgruppe%5D=0&cHash=69c2978df7ab94262c40a535ae021a1d";
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        List<WebElement> addresses = driver.findElements(By.className("entryshort"));
        for(WebElement address : addresses) {
            String strasse = address.findElement(By.className("strasse")).getText();
            String plzort = address.findElement(By.className("plzort")).getText();
            System.out.println(strasse + "  " + plzort);
        }
        WebElement nextButton = driver.findElement(By.className("next"));
        if (driver != null){
            nextButton.click();
        }   
    }
}
```

So far so good. The output is displayed like this:

Landower Stra�e 15 18573 Dreschvitz
Schmalbeinstra�e 32 50674 K�ln

Clearly it is not UTF-8 encoded.

Expected Output:

Landower Stra**ß**e 15  18573 Dreschvitz
Schmalbeinstra**ß**e 32  50674 K**ö**ln

I have tried everything I could think of / find to solve this, but failed so far.

Any ideas how I can ensure correct output?

Comment: "_everything I could think of_" - Can you share some of these things, by editing the question?

Comment: This may be because your console `System.out.println(...)` is not using the correct encoding. Are you running your code at the command line? In an IDE? Can you share details? Maybe research some of [these answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=output+console+not+utf-8+site:stackoverflow.com), if you have not done so already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is with your IDE console, which doesn't support UTF-8 encoding.

At OS level you can use:

```
-Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

**In IntelliJ Idea you can set the encoding:**

[image]

**In Eclipse:**

Preferences > General > Workspace, set Text file encoding to Other : UTF-8

[image]

**I have checked your code and even tried to write the data on to .txt file and it was working fine for me**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String baseUrl = "https://www.dhs.de/service/suchthilfeverzeichnis?tx_wwdhseinrichtung2_fe1%5Baction%5D=list&tx_wwdhseinrichtung2_fe1%5Bangebot%5D=0&tx_wwdhseinrichtung2_fe1%5Bbland%5D=0&tx_wwdhseinrichtung2_fe1%5Bcontroller%5D=Entry&tx_wwdhseinrichtung2_fe1%5Bdo%5D=search&tx_wwdhseinrichtung2_fe1%5Bplzort%5D=&tx_wwdhseinrichtung2_fe1%5Bspezi%5D=0&tx_wwdhseinrichtung2_fe1%5Bsprache%5D=0&tx_wwdhseinrichtung2_fe1%5Bumkreis%5D=0&tx_wwdhseinrichtung2_fe1%5Bzielgruppe%5D=0&cHash=69c2978df7ab94262c40a535ae021a1d";
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--headless");
    options.addArguments("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36");
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    List<WebElement> addresses = driver.findElements(By.className("entryshort"));
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("scrap_data.txt", true);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    for(WebElement address : addresses) {
        String strasse = address.findElement(By.className("strasse")).getText();
        String plzort = address.findElement(By.className("plzort")).getText();
        System.out.println(strasse + "  " + plzort);
        bw.write(strasse);
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write(plzort);
        bw.newLine();
    }
    bw.close();
    WebElement nextButton = driver.findElement(By.className("next"));
    if (driver != null){
        nextButton.click();
    }
}
```

**My output:**
[image]

**There is one feedback and addition you can do with your code:** while scrapping you should add two addArguments "headless" chrome and "user-agent".

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--headless");
    options.addArguments("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36");
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```